# Pester having problems with else statement

Tags: powershell, pester

Hey guys so I have this code (Powershell v5), and when I run the pester for it, the else statement is not being detected. Runs perfectly fine on powershell v7 but need it to run on v5.
Source Code

```
Function 'INeedHelp'


$array= [Systems.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$GettingInfo= #Function that's calling an object with properties
$String= 'Example'
$x= $null
$x= $GettingInfo | Where-Object { $._item -like "*$String*" -or $._ $thing like 
"*$String*"}
if($x){
      $array.Add($x)
      if($array.thing -like *Example*) {
            $array | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name Match -Value $true
      }      
}
else {
    return 'fail'
}
```

Pester

```
Mock 'Function' {
    return[PSCustomObject]@(
    item = 'hello'
    thing= 'bye'
    )
}
It 'Should be able to get the failure result'
$Result=  INeedHelp
$Result | Should -be 'fail'
```

The error is expected 'fail' but got @{item= 'hello'; thing= 'bye'}

Comment: it should be `[PSCustomObject]@{...}`.

Comment: Have you tried running your *exact* sample code locally? There appear to be multiple issues - for example ```$x= $GettingInfo | Where-Object { $._item -like "*$String*" -or $._ $thing like 
"*$String*"}``` - ```$._item``` and ```$._ $thing```. It’s hard to tell if these are the root issues in your original code, or typos you made while anonymising your question.  If you cut&paste you code from your question and run it do you see the same issue as in your real script?

Answer (score 0):

You are Mocking the `INeedHelp` function so that it always returns an object with two properties. You'll never get a test to therefore return `fail` because your test will always invoke the Mock and this only returns one result.

If the purpose of your test is to test the `INeedHelp` function, then Mocking it is the wrong approach as the real code for the function never gets executed.

Instead, based on the code you've put above (which has quite a few syntax errors FYI) you want to be creating a Mock of whatever the function is that returns values to the `$GettingInfo` variable. You can have different Mocks of this function return different values at different points of your test script and in doing so can ensure that there are tests that enter both parts of the function's `if` statement.

Here's a working example to show you what I mean:

```
function Get-InfoFunction {}

function Example {
    $GettingInfo = Get-InfoFunction

    if ($GettingInfo -is [string]) {
        return 'string'
    }
    else {
        return 'fail'
    }
}

Describe 'MyTests' {

    Context 'String input' {

        BeforeAll {
            Mock Get-InfoFunction { Return 'hello' }
        }

        It 'Should return string' {
            Example | Should -Be 'string'
        }
    }

    Context 'Non-string input' {

        BeforeAll {
            Mock Get-InfoFunction { Return 7 }
        }

        It 'Should return fail' {
            Example | Should -Be 'fail'
        }
    }
}
```